# How to load using logstash in AWS Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I didn't find any proper documentation in output plugins of logsatsh ,for loading data into AWS ES,i do find

output plugin only speaks the HTTP protocol. without specifying port 9200 can we load data in AWS ES

```
   input {
            jdbc {
                jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://localhost/elasticsearch"
                jdbc_user => "root"
                jdbc_password => "empower"
                #jdbc_validate_connection => true
                jdbc_driver_library => "/home/wtc082/Documents/com.mysql.jdbc_5.1.5.jar"
                jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
                statement => "SELECT * FROM index_part_content_local LIMIT 10;"
                schedule => "1 * * * *"
                #codec => "json"
            }
        }

    output {
        elasticsearch {
            index => "mysqltest"
            document_type => "mysqltest_type"
            document_id => "%{partnum}"
            hosts => "AWSURI"
        }
    }
```

Can we do like this ?

Comment: What happens if you try? You might need to specify port 80 as it defaults to 9200 if not specified.

Comment: Hi val ,when i run this conf file with local ES its working fine,

Comment: when loading to AWS ES its giving me the following error                                                     [400] {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"invalid_type_name_exception","reason":"Document mapping type name can't start with '_', found: [_template]"}],"type":"invalid_type_name_exception","reason":"Document mapping type name can't start with '_', found: [_template]"},"status":400} {:class=>"Elasticsearch::Transport::Transport::Errors::BadRequest", :level=>:error}

Comment: it gave above error but the data was successfully loaded in AWS,can we neglect this error or m i doing something wrong

Comment: An error is never a good thing. What version of ES do you have locally and which one are you using on AWS?

Comment: my local ES is 2.4 and AWS is of 5.1.1

Comment: Can you try 5.1.1 locally and see if you get the same error? There were many changes between both versions. Probably that adding `"manage_template" => false` in your `elasticsearch` output does the trick.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138293/discussion-between-prasad-khandagale-and-val).

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I was using the log stash 2.4 to load data from Mysql to ES 5.X version when I used the log stash 5.X version it solved my issue.I didn't get any error while running the conf file

Thanks Val